# WifiP2pManager.initialize returns null

Tags: android-wifi, wifi-direct

WifiP2pManager.initialize returns null. I am using Droid 4, Android version 4.0.4 and built my app with API level 14.

```
...
```

_p2pChannel = _p2pManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), 
                                    new WifiP2pManager.ChannelListener() {

```
@Override
public void onChannelDisconnected() {
     Log.e(TAG, "Peer-to-peer manager channel disconnected.");
     //TODO: Manage the re-creation of the channel
     _p2pChannel = null;
}
});

if (_p2pChannel == null) {
    Log.e(TAG, "P2P Manager failed to initialize.");
    return;
}

....
```

Android Manifest has:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />    

<uses-feature 
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi.direct" 
    android:required="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess WiFiDirect is simply not supported on the Droid4. Can someone confirm? It is not on the list of WiFiDirect certified devices: http://certifications.wi-fi.org/pdf_certificate.php?cid=WFA12854

Answer (score 0):

Its because of your emulator probably,i'd this problem and rum my app in native android emulator(android studio) and my problem was solved